# Multiple dex files define-volley

Tags: android

error when build apk....
[enter image description here][1]

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/volley/VolleyError;

my gradle :

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.morten.gpibwal.desakayuambon"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
    dexOptions {

    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:volley-integration:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: i love u @IntelliJAmiya

Work like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Lcom/android/volley/VolleyError;

You should delete

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:volley-integration:1.4.0'
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is

```
 delete "compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:volley-integration:1.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

add  `multiDexEnabled true` in gradle file also use same version for `compile dependencies` check below code

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.morten.gpibwal.desakayuambon"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true 

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
    dexOptions {

    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:volley-integration:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

remove unnecessary empty

```
  dexOptions {

        }
```